# 承認済み回答がソート順トップに固定表示されていても良いですか？

Tags: 討議, 完了

少し前に、[StackOverflow で回答を並べ替える方法を変更しました](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411352/)。デフォルトでは、回答は投票によって厳密に並べ替えられ（最高スコアから降順）、リスト内で承認された回答の順序はスコアに基づいています。この[アイデアは 2013年から議論されてきたもので](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326095/please-unpin-the-accepted-answer-from-the-top)、現在は実装されています。

各コミュニティサイト毎に、従来通りのピン留めを維持するか、スコア順での並べ替えに変更するかを [話し合いによって決めています](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369914) 。

スタック・オーバーフローでも、承認されたかどうかではなく、スコア順に表示するかどうかを選択したいと思います。

一緒に決めましょう。どうぞあなたの考えを教えてください！

---

**アップデート**

この議論に基づいて、承認された回答の固定を解除しました。現在、すべての回答は投票に基づいて並べ替えられています。

Answer (score 10):

回答の承認はあくまで質問者の主観であり、かつ「回答してくれてありがとう」くらいの意味合いでマークを付けていると思われるものも稀に見かけられます。
ピン留めを外し、純粋に高スコアな回答がより上位に表示されるようになった方が閲覧者にとっては役立つかもしれません。

一方で、承認された回答にはコメント欄で役立つ追加情報 (回答を参考に私の環境では 〇〇 したら解決しました等) が含まれるケースもあるので、ピン留めを外すとしても **承認された回答にジャンプできる方法** が用意されていると便利になると思います。([既に MSE でも同様のアイデアが出されています](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369839))

[image]