# コミュニティユーザーの質問ピックアップ動作について

Tags: 討議, 機能の要求

[コミュニティ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/%e3%82%b3%e3%83%9f%e3%83%a5%e3%83%8b%e3%83%86%e3%82%a3)ユーザーの行っていることの一つに未回答(未解決)の質問をピックアップして目立つようにする動作がありますが：

> - 未回答の質問を、１時間毎にランダムに、一覧のトップにピックアップして、目立つようにしています。

多くの割合で、**質問者自身が既にこのサイトを長期間訪れていない** 質問が含まれています。

中にはその時点で回答を書いても有用になるであろう一般化の容易な質問があるかもしれないし、既にある回答に他の人がプラス投票して評価が進むかもしれませんが、大部分は質問者がサイトを見に来て結果を書いてくれない限り有効/無効が明確化出来ないものだと思われます。

質問者が訪れていない質問は、せっかく目立たせてもそれによって却って新し目の質問がトップから下がっていって回答されるチャンス/注目度が減る可能性も考えられます。

サイトが長期間運営されているとそうした質問/質問者も増えてくると思われるので、ピックアップする質問を選ぶ基準を見直して、質問者が長期間このサイトを訪れていない質問はピックアップ対象から外してみてはどうでしょう？

例えばこちらの質問を削除する動作があり、長いのは1年で判定しているので、それと同様またはもう少し長い期間の後でピックアップ対象から外すとかが考えられます。

> - [放棄されたと思われる質問を削除します](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/92006)

---

**付いた回答の一部内容に関して：**

以下の点はまあ否めないですが、

> 質問者が長期間訪れているかどうかでまとめてしまうのは大雑把すぎる気がします。

こちらに関しては、記事を削除する訳ではないし、そうした人たちはアクティブな記事のリストに頼らず自力で検索するでしょうからピックアップしなくても問題無いし、今回の提案はピックアップしないというだけなので記事自身の有用性を損なうものでは無いと考えます。

> **同様の問題に悩み質問ページを訪問した閲覧者にとって有用** になり得ます。

こちらはそういう手段があったのかとは思いますが、

> **クローズ票を投じる** と有効だと思います。

[質問が [クローズ済み] とは？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)
[クローズ票および再オープンの投票](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions)
上記のヘルプ記事をみるかぎり、5票必要だったり4日後にしきい値に達しなかったら期限切れになるなど、常時対処しようとする人が少ない場合には効力を発揮しないのでは？
モデレーターなら一人の判断で出来るようですが、それはそれでモデレーターの負担が増えてしまうでしょう。

時々開催される「もくもく会」などで集中的に対処するといったことをすれば良いかもしれませんね。

---

ちなみに完全に別件ですが、以下とは反対にピックアップされたことが切っ掛けと思われるマイナス投票を受けたことが複数回あります。

> そして回答にプラス票が投じられれば、

質問者自身はサイトを訪れておらず長期間放置された質問＆回答で、特に回答に間違いが見つかった/状況が変わった/質問に合っていない/判り難いとかのコメントも無くマイナス投票だけされたので、何の改善等しようも無いものでした。

そうした事例に関する提案を以下にしているので、そちらにも目を通してもらえれば幸いです。
[ヘルプセンター: 「マイナス投票する」の...に代わるものは？の候補追加](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3412/26370)

---

**次の回答に対して：**

> 今回の例に当てはめるなら「投稿者のアクティビティ」ではなく「投稿そのものの鮮度」で判断すれば十分だと思います。

「鮮度」というのが何を表しているのかちょっと分かりませんが、言葉のイメージ/感覚で言うなら、割と「投稿者のアクティビティ」(あるいは回答者も加わるのかも)と相関が高そうな雰囲気なのですが？

「投稿者のアクティビティ」が無いということは、それ以上のコミュニケーションや変化が発生しない可能性が高いと考えられるので、それは「コミュニティのトピック」としては停滞している(埃をかぶっている)と言えるのでは？

まあ「鮮度」が計量・計測可能であれば、それを元に調整すれば良いと思われます。

繰り返しますがそういう「投稿者のアクティビティ」の無い質問＆回答の記事そのものには何かしようとは言っていません。
ただそれ自身の進展・変化が見込めなさそうだし直近・最近の投稿への注目度にも影響しそうだから、「ピックアップ対象から外してはどうでしょう？」という提案です。

ちなみに以前こちらに記事そのものへの評価を代行してしまおうという提案があって賛同は多くなかったようですね。
[コミュニティによってトップへ挙げられた質問に回答した場合、ユーザーがもう現れそうもない場合](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2678/26370)

Answer (score 3):

> 大部分は質問者がサイトを見に来て結果を書いてくれない限り有効/無効が明確化出来ないもの

ある質問に有効な回答が可能かは個別に議論されるべきで、質問者が長期間訪れているかどうかでまとめてしまうのは大雑把すぎる気がします。問題に関する情報が十分に与えられており、正しい回答が可能な場合、「同様の現象に対して次のように対処した（すれば良いのではないか）」といった回答は、**同様の問題に悩み質問ページを訪問した閲覧者にとって有用**になり得ます。そして回答にプラス票が投じられれば、コミュニティユーザーによるピックアップの対象から外れます<sup>[[1]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19739)</sup>。

> ### Who is the "Community" User?<sup>[[1]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19739)</sup>
>
> > * Questions with at least 30 days of no activity, at least one answer scoring zero, and no answers scoring above that. Questions that are locked or closed will not be bumped. The Community User will only bump a maximum of one question per hour.

また、そもそも「問題解決には追加情報が必要」な場合や、「正しい答えがいくつもあり、どれが正しいかを判断できない」場合には、**クローズ票を投じる**と有効だと思います。そのような質問のクローズ理由には「より詳細に、または明確にする必要がある」や「より焦点を絞る必要がある」が挙げられます。加えて、クローズされ一定条件を満たした質問は abandoned closed として削除されるため<sup>[[2]](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/roomba)</sup>、結果的に回答の不可能な質問がピックアップされなくなります。

> ### 私の質問がCommunityユーザーに削除されたのはなぜですか？ <sup>[[2]](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/roomba)</sup>
>
> **`9` 日以上前にクローズされた質問で、かつ...**
>
> - クローズ理由が「重複」ではない
> - スコアが 0 以下
> - ロックされていない
> - スコア 1 以上の回答がついていない
> - 承認済みの回答がない
> - 再オープン票が入っていない
> - 過去 9 日間に編集されていない
>
> ものは abandoned closed として削除され、 `RemoveAbandonedClosed` と表記されます。

---

一方で、新しい質問がピックアップされた古い質問に流され、回答を得る機会を失なっている可能性がある点には、ある程度の対処が必要だと思います。個人的には、スタック・オーバーフローにおいて「1時間に1つ未回答の質問をピックアップする」という、ピックアップ機能による**ピックアップの頻度が日毎の質問数に対して高すぎる**のではないかと思います。

次の画像は[Stack Exchangeネットワークのサイト一覧](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#traffic)で、スタック・オーバーフローを見たときのスクリーンショットです（2021年12月13日）。この画像を見ると、スタック・オーバーフローでは一日に**約9件**の質問が投稿されています。それに対してコミュニティーユーザーが一日でピックアップする質問の件数は**最大24件**です。ピックアップされる質問の方が2倍以上多いことから、ピックアップの頻度がピックアップ機能による新規質問への弊害をより強めている可能性もあるかもしれないと考えています。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 「付いた回答の一部内容に関して」について、コメントで返信します。 / 
回答の最初の段落は、必ずしも「質問者がサイトを見に来て結果を書いてくれない限り有効/無効が明確化出来ない」わけではない、という趣旨で書いた部分でした。十分な情報が与えられている質問であれば、そのような状況はほとんどないという個人的な感覚も入っていますが...。

Comment: 対処しようとする人が少ない場合には効果がないのは仰る通りですね...。ただピックアップ機能に関係なく、回答が不可能で、かつ質問者が改善しない状態となった質問は、クローズされるのが妥当な流れだと思います。対処しようとする人が少ないために質問がクローズされなかった場合は、モデレータへ通報するか、メタで提起するかのどちらかになりそうです。もしくはメタでクローズ票の閾値を下げる提案をしてみるのも良いかもしれません。

Answer (score 2):

#### 短い回答:

少し前に [承認済み回答のピン留めを外した](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3641) ように、"質問者自身による承認" はそこまで重要ではありません。

スタックオーバーフローにおいては「誰が投稿したか」より、あくまで「投稿の質」で評価されるべきであり、今回の例に当てはめるなら「投稿者のアクティビティ」ではなく「投稿そのものの鮮度」で判断すれば十分だと思います。

#### 補足:

いわゆる「つっつき (Bump)」は一時間に一回を基本としていますが、実際にはもう少し細かいルールの元に実施されています。
まだまだ投稿が活発ではない SOja では、トップページに一定以上の Bump 済み投稿が溜まっている場合、古い投稿が流れるまで新しい Bump は行わないように独自の調整をしているようです <sup>[[2]](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7542448#7542448)</sup>。
(実際の動きを見ても、12時間以上の間隔を空けている場合が確かにあります)

Answer (score 0):

有用な回答が付いているにもかかわらず、質問者が逃げたために回答として承認されないままの質問があります。コミュニティユーザーはこういった質問を好んでピックアップしているような印象があります。そういった問題は追加回答しようがなくピックアップ行為が邪魔に感じられます。

ですので、「回答が１つもない」という条件を付けるのはどうでしょうか？

Comment: この場合はその回答に +1 vote を加えて合計がプラスの投票になれば「未解決の質問」ではなくなってピックアップされなくなるように理解していたのですが、そうではない挙動をしていますでしょうか？